# Mismatching Geometry records (using SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY()) when retrieving data using OPENQUERY from Oracle linked server to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, openquery, wkt

The overall aim is to retrieve geometric data in the form of well-known text 'WKT Geometry' along with columns 'ID' and 'REFERENCE' from our oracle database into our SQL Server database by using `OPENQUERY` to access the oracle linked server database

We used the `SDO.UTIL_TO_WKT()` function to enable us to retrieve Oracle's geometric datatype (SDO) into SQL Server in the well-known-text format (which we named the 'WKT Geometry' column). The WKT datatype is readable by T-SQL where the SDO datatype isn't.

The problem is, when creating the table in SQL Server, the rows in the WKT geometry column get disordered with the records from the ID and REFERENCE columns.

However, the records in the `ID` and `REFERENCE` columns do align properly with source data.

This is all the syntax we have tried:

```
--Select into tables -- 

--'Select * into': 
select * into [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] FROM OPENQUERY (ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) FROM ORACLE_TABLE'); 

--'Select * into' with 'ORDER BY' in openquery: 

select * into [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] FROM OPENQUERY (ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) FROM ORACLE_TABLE ORDER BY REFERENCE'); 

--'Select * into' with 'ORDER BY' outside and inside the open query: 

select * into [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] FROM OPENQUERY (ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) FROM ORACLE_TABLE ORDER BY REFERENCE') ORDER BY REFERENCE; 

--'Select * into' with 'WHERE' clause 'REFERENCE = REFERENCE' 

select * into [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] FROM OPENQUERY (ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) FROM ORACLE_TABLE WHERE REFERENCE = REFERENCE'); 

--'Select * into' with 'WHERE' clause 'REFERENCE = REFERENCE' inside openquery and out select * into [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] FROM OPENQUERY (ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) FROM ORACLE_TABLE WHERE REFERENCE = REFERENCE') WHERE REFERENCE = REFERENCE; 

--'INSERT INTO' Tables -- 

-- 'INSERT INTO' 

INSERT INTO [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] (ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY) SELECT ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) AS WKTGEOMETRY FROM ORACLE_TABLE'); 

--'INSERT INTO' with 'ORDER BY REFERENCE' 

INSERT INTO [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] (ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY) SELECT ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) AS WKTGEOMETRY FROM ORACLE_TABLE order by REFERENCE'); -

-'INSERT INTO' with 'ORDER BY REFERENCE' inside and outside of open query 

INSERT INTO [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] (ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY) SELECT ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) AS WKTGEOMETRY FROM ORACLE_TABLE ORDER BY REFERENCE') Order by Reference; 

--'INSERT INTO' with 'WHERE' clause 'REFERENCE = REFERENCE' 

INSERT INTO [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] (ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY) SELECT ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) AS WKTGEOMETRY FROM ORACLE_TABLE where REFERENCE = REFERENCE') Order by Reference; 

--'INSERT INTO' with 'WHERE' clause 'REFERENCE = REFERENCE' inside openquery and out 

INSERT INTO [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] (ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY) SELECT ID, REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT ID, REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) AS WKTGEOMETRY FROM ORACLE_TABLE where REFERENCE = REFERENCE') where REFERENCE = REFERENCE Order by Reference; 

-- Make a Join with itself: 

SELECT * FROM (SELECT REFERENCE, WKTGEOMETRY FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) AS WKTGEOMETRY FROM ORACLE_TABLE') ) AS subquery1 JOIN ( SELECT REFERENCE, ID FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT REFERENCE, ID FROM ORACLE_TABLE') ) AS subquery2 ON subquery1.REFERENCE = subquery2.REFERENCE ORDER BY subquery2.REFERENCE; 

--Join oracle with sql table
SELECT A.REFERENCE, A.ID, B.WKTGEOMETRY
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] as A
INNER JOIN OPENQUERY(ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) AS WKTGEOMETRY FROM ORACLE_TABLE ') AS  B
    ON A.REFERENCE = B.REFERENCE order by REFERENCE;
 
--update sql table using the columns within the oracle table

UPDATE [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE]
SET WKTGEOMETRY = oq.WKTGEOMETRY
FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE_SERVER, 'SELECT REFERENCE, SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) AS WKTGEOMETRY FROM ORACLE_TABLE) oq
WHERE [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE].REFERENCE = oq.REFERENCE;
```

Here is an example that occurs across the table:

How the polygon should look like:

[Reference AI/02/0145 on the original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMkiU.png)

This is what gets inserted in instead:

[Reference AI/02/0145 on the destination table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuyHG.png)

However, if just one record gets inserted then it works, but as soon as there are few more inserts, then it fails. I presume it gets confused and doesn't know where to insert the geometry, so we then created a spatial index on the geometry column on the destination table, however we can't insert plain text (what the SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) command retrieves) into a Geometry type column.

We have tried all the above scripts with absolutely no joy.

Has anybody come across such an issue with the GEOMETRY type?

Kind regards,

Carlos

Comment: What does "when creating the table in SQL, the records in the WKT Geometry column get disordered with the records from the ID and REFERENCE Columns." mean?  Please simplify your post to a single reproducible problem.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: David Browne: It means that the reference and id columns get inserted correctly, whereas the geometry doesn't as the polygon information goes into the wrong row. Please see the images I added onto the post
RF 1991: It's tagged sql-server already

Comment: maybe something with the driver, so you mean that first row gets polygon from second row? if you just select data, is it also wrong?

Comment: the actual picture of geometry representation i wouldn't trust though, the question is if wkt are the same. you also generally need to create a proper SRID for your geometry instances, see STGeomFromText function

Comment: siggemannen: I am not sure about the driver, any suggestion?. So, basically the first row gets a polygon from a random row, second row gets polygon from a different row, third row gets polygon from a different one, etc. etc. Yes, when I select the data it's wrong as all the polygons are assigned to the wrong id and reference. All the polygon info doesn't go into the right row and they are all mixed up (be aware we have nearly 35000 rows). Yes, we have used wkt instead of wbt and the SRID is correct at the source table, as it's the OSGB British National Grid, hence 27700

Comment: what driver did you use to create the linked server? maybe something wrong with it

Comment: siggerman the driver is 19c. We have managed to solve the issue by using the following script:

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVERNAME, 'SELECT CAST(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, 4000,1) as VARCHAR2(4000)) as DATA_CLOB,
CAST(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, 4000,4001) as VARCHAR2(4000)) DATA_CLOB2,
CAST(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, 4000,8001) as VARCHAR2(4000)) as DATA_CLOB3,
CAST(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, 4000,12001) as VARCHAR2(4000)) as DATA_CLOB4,
CAST(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, 4000,16001) as VARCHAR2(4000)) AS DATA_CLOB5
FROM TABLENAME')

And then inserting it into our new table :)

Comment: There's nothing about LOBs in your original question :) But i'm glad you solved it!